# How can I program my movement to be more "linear"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a bit of an issue with movement. The game is a 3D FPS and the current code I have has a few issues and I was wondering how I would go about making "Minecraft Like" movement.

```
public Rigidbody PlayerRb;

public Transform PlayerTran;

public float speed = 2500f;
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
    {
        PlayerRb.AddForce(PlayerTran.forward * speed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
    {
        PlayerRb.AddForce(PlayerTran.right * -speed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("s"))
    {
        PlayerRb.AddForce(PlayerTran.forward * -speed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
    {
        PlayerRb.AddForce(PlayerTran.right * speed);
    }

}
```

If anyone could help me make better movement that would be greatly appreciated. I am pretty new so sorry if I don't get it the first time.

Comment: Use `.MovePosition`  instead of `.AddForce`

Comment: Almost perfect, using this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html I was able to make the player move in a perfect way. now the only issue is it does not follow the camera. Like if I'm looking forward I want to go forward from the camera's perspective, I just go forward in one global way.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed all issues with this code
https://github.com/Saharsh1223/Minecraft-player-movement-in-unity-free-download/blob/main/Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs

Comment: Thank you for answering your question! It might be helpful to others viewing your question in the future to see a copied version of your code and specifically what you changed so that they can see what solved your problem.

Comment: Alright, thanks for telling me next time I will show that.